# How to Download an AssetBundle and then save it in the device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets, assetbundle

I'm using the LoadFromCacheOrDownload function, I'm just not sure how can I just download the asset bundle from inside unity and then load the asset bundle for a local in the device. Thank you! Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;


public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour
{
public string sceneAssetBundle;
public string sceneName;
public string sName;
public string bName;
public string BundleURL;
public int version;
public int downloaded = 0;


IEnumerator Start() {
    if (downloaded == 0){
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (BundleURL, version)) {
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception ("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            if (www.error == null) {
                AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
            }
        }
            if (Caching.ready == true) {
                downloaded = 1;
                yield return InitializeLevelAsync (sceneName, true);

            }
        }
    }


public void getScene(string sName){
    sceneName = sName;

}

public void getBundle(string bName){
    sceneAssetBundle = bName;

}


public IEnumerator InitializeLevelAsync (string levelName, bool isAdditive)
{
    // This is simply to get the elapsed time for this phase of AssetLoading.
    float startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

    // Load level from assetBundle.
    AssetBundleLoadOperation request = AssetBundleManager.LoadLevelAsync(sceneAssetBundle, levelName, isAdditive);
    if (request == null)
        yield break;
    yield return StartCoroutine(request);

    // Calculate and display the elapsed time.
    float elapsedTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - startTime;
    Debug.Log("Finished loading scene " + levelName + " in " + elapsedTime + " seconds" );
}
}
```

Comment: So which part of the code is not working? I looked at it and it looks fine...

Comment: Well, it works for the first time, but when I try to run it again it tries to download the bundle a second time, which Unity doesn't let me. Using Unload() wouldn't be ideal for me since we'll be using large asset bundles in the future.

Comment: That's what AssetBundle is for. It will download and cache the Asset. In order to download the asset again you first have to unload it first. Why are you trying to download it multiple times?

Comment: Well... Exactly, I don't want to download it multiple times, just one. Is LoadFromCacheOrDownload the right method? (Sorry if I sound kinda rude right now, english is not my main language)

Comment: You don't sound rude.  I think I get it now. Please remove the current AssetBundle you downloaded for now. Put `Debug.Log("Called");` inside `if (Caching.ready == true) {`and run your code again. I want to know if that is actually being called.

Comment: Well... it's kinda weird that nothing shows up on the Console, even using the Debug.Log("Called"). ): Maybe it's a Unity bug or something. Also, I'm using the Vuforia plugin in my scenes, might be related to it.

Comment: just needed to restart the unity and the "Called" showed up.

Comment: Ok. I really want to know if "Called" shows up **first time** you run it. Can you do that again. Delete the AssetBundle, restart Unity and run it again. check if "Called is displayed for the first time. I have an answer but I want to be sure that this is the problem before posting.

Comment: Yup, it shows up in the first time, but not in the second one, the only thing that shows up is the "The AssetBundle 'path'(I'm using a local file url just for tests) can't be loaded because another AssetBundle with the same files is already loaded." error

Comment: Try my solution and let me know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Would I be to annoying to add that it doesn't works in the build mode? Only inside the editor and with the simulation mode turned on.

Comment: But really, thanks a lot

Comment: It should work everywhere. `PlayerPrefs` works in every platform. If it doesn't work, add `PlayerPrefs.Save();` after `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AssetLoaded", 1);`.

Comment: The weird problem is that it doesn't loads the scenes once I click the buttons, but I don't think it's a problem with this script in particular, I'll keep looking, but again, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: You can create a new post for this new problem. Just make sure to post code required to replicate the problem. A Button and the loadScene code. I will give it a try if I can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `PlayerPrefs` to know when Asset is downloaded, Check if it has been downloaded before attempting to download it again. Here is an example

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("AssetLoaded", 0) == 0)
{
    //Save that we have down loaded Asset 
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AssetLoaded", 1);
    Debug.Log("Asset has NOT been downloaded. Downloading....");

    //DOWNLOAD ASSET HERE
    //.......
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Asset already loaded. Can't download it again!");
}
```

To incorporate this with the code in your question:

```
IEnumerator Start() {
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("AssetLoaded", 0) == 0){
        Debug.Log("Asset has NOT been downloaded. Downloading....");
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (BundleURL, version)) {
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception ("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            if (www.error == null) {
                AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
            }
        }
            if (Caching.ready == true) {
                downloaded = 1;
                //Save that we have down loaded Asset 
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AssetLoaded", 1);
                yield return InitializeLevelAsync (sceneName, true);

            }
        }else
          {
             Debug.Log("Asset already loaded. Can't download it again! Loading it instead");
             yield return InitializeLevelAsync (sceneName, true);
          }
    }
```

To Reset it, simply call `PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("AssetLoaded");`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! The only alteration I needed to make is to add the                 yield return InitializeLevelAsync (sceneName, true); inside the else.

Comment: @IsabelleBrandelero I just did that and I also added a way to reset it. Take a look at the updated code. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to use LoadFromCacheOrDownload function because obviously it saves whatever you want to download in the cache memory, it's something you don't want, since that memory could only be loaded but not deleted through the code.

The best possible solution for me is to use WebClient.

How does it work?

1. You must import the C# System.Net library (using System.Net;)
2. Since downloading a file is not something immediate, you must use a coroutine, which will allow you to wait until the file is downloaded.
3. How to Download an AssetBundle or any File in Code

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using UnityEngine;
   using System;
   using System.Net; //Most important Library

   public class DownloadClass: MonoBehaviour
   {
           //Your URL path
           string url = "https://yourUrl.com/fileName.extension";

           //Create a WebRequest instance
           Uri uri = new Uri(url);

           //Create a Client instance to download the WebRequest
           WebClient client = new WebClient();

           //Suscribe to the event ProgressChanged
           client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;

           //Create your coroutine to download your AssetBundle or any file (mp3, jpeg, etc)
           public IEnumerator DownLoadAsset()
           {
                   //Start download and specify the save path
                   client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, Application.persistentDataPath + "/yourPath/fileName");

                   while(client.IsBusy)   // Wait until the file download is complete
                           yield return null;

                   //Now your file is completely downloaded and saved
           }

           //Create your ProgressChanged "Listener"
           private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
           {
                   //Show download progress
                   Debug.Log("Download Progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage);
           }

   }
   ```
4. How to Load an AssetBundle or any File in Code

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using UnityEngine;
   using System;

   public class LoadClass : MonoBehaviour
   {
           //Variable to hold the asset bundle
           private AssetBundle bundle;

           public void LoadAsset()
           {
                   //Check to load the bundle only once
                   if (bundle != null)
                           bundle.Unload(true);

                   //Load an AssetBundle in a specific path
                   bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Application.persistentDataPath + "/yourPath/fileName");

                   //Your file is Now loaded, you can access to your data              
           }
   }
   ```
5. How to Delete an AssetBundle or any File in Code

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using UnityEngine;
   using System;
   using System.IO;  //Most important Library

   public class DeleteClass : MonoBehaviour
   {
           public void DeleteAsset()
           {
                   //If the file exits, Delete the file
                   if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/yourPath/fileName"))
                           File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/yourPath/fileName");

                   //Your file was delete from memory
           }
   }
   ```

I hope this solutions work's for you.

Comment: "since that memory could only be loaded but not deleted through the code". why can't it be garbage collected?

Comment: Unity is an excellent engine, but unfortunately, not everything is perfect. Sometimes Unity does not behave as expected. I prefer to handle the behavior that I want in the game, instead of leaving all the behavior to Unity. Garbage Collection is great, but for large files that are packaged in an AssetBundle, it is better to handle yourself where the AssetBundle should be saved and in the same way, be able to delete the file in the exact place where it was saved.

Comment: Nothing in your code uses unsafe memory operations. I was trying to be polite and point to a flawed reason. I would delete it before people start to pile on it

Comment: Unity developed a way of handling large files in garbage collection and it is called incremental garbage collection. This form is not supported by WebGL and you need to use .NET 4.x to use it. This mode is not perfect yet, the way I manage the memory it works without problem when exporting for any device, even if it is an old device (2010). I just wanted to share the most optimal solution that exists so far.

Comment: As you please. Logging off